# A smaller Stanford NLP Models Jar file

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am currently utilizing this JAR file for the Stanford NLP models: stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar

This file is pretty big: its about 340 MB.

I am only using 4 models: `tokenize`, `ssplit`, `parse`, and `lemma`. Is there any way that I can use a smaller model JAR file (or is there a JAR file for each individual model) because I absolutely need the size of this file to be as small as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine if you just include the parser's model file in your classpath and the pos tagger's model file.  "lemma" requires "pos" , so you will need to include that in your list of annotators.

For instance: "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" and "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" should be all you need.

You could just create that directory structure and include those files in your classpath, or make a jar with just those files in it.  You can definitely cut out most of that jar.

The bottom line is that if you're missing something, your code will crash with a missing resources error.  So you simply need to keep adding files until the code stops crashing.  You definitely don't need a lot of the files in that jar.

Answer (score 0):

Following similar approach as mentioned by @StanfordNLPHelp, I used maven-shade-plugin and reduced the size of my final compiled jar file. You need to change "Package.MainClass" and the `includes` tag or add `excludes` tags

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <!-- adding Main-Class to manifest file -->
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>Package.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:models</artifact>
                            <includes>
                                <include>edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of StanfordNLPHelp, I did this (I use Gradle):

- Downloaded the CoreNLP from:
  [Stanford CoreNLP download](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html)
- Unjar the stanford-corenlp-X-models.jar
- go /edu/Stanford/nlp/models
- delete folders which are not relevant. Unfortunately this is a bit guess and check
- Rezip the folder and convert it into a jar (I simply just changed the extension, which might be a bit frowned upon)
- Add a libs folder to my gradle project ./app/libs
- Move stanford-corenlp-x.jar from the download in there and the new jar made above
- In the build.gradle add

  ```
    implementation files('libs/stanford-corenlp-4.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/stanford-corenlp-4.4.0-models.jar')
  ```
- Run gradle build. If there is an error, you deleted an important file. Revert and rezip, and so on.